# Can't find the overrides or emulation tabs in chrome 2016?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to view the emulation panel but I can't find it anywhere. Everywhere I've looked it says to open an overrides panel to find it but that's missing too. I also can't find any helpful or new answers to my question. Pressing esc only opens up console and there's nothing in settings that seems to help. Can someone please tell me how to reach it?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of emulation in the drawer [Device Mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/?hl=en) is now offered for emulating other devices. It provides many benefits over the old emulation mode, such as taking into account the meta viewport tag on render. So what you see is much closer to what you'd get in real life.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit) on a Mac.

1. Cmd-Opt-i to open console.
2. Click the button with three vertical dots and the very top right of the Developer Tools window.
3. Select: more tools > sensors:

If the console draw is not already open it will open. Either way there should now be a sensors tab next to the console tab on the console draw. Click this tab and follow your nose from there.

Note that this tab had an x by it. Hitting this will hide the sensors tab and next time you use it you will need to follow the steps above again to reinstate it.